GCP App Engine Custom Domains Not Reflecting AA and AAAA records
I'm adding a few custom domains to my app engine as part of Google Tag Manager server-side configuration. I have verified the client main domain as well as the sub-domain and then generated the AA ands AAAA records from the GCP console. The development team has confirmed that they have updated the DNS record and I've verified the same by pinging the domain too.
However the console is still showing only CNAME instead of AA or AAAA. And I also don't see any valid certificate IDs.
This is how it's reflecting at my end
I'd expect the UI to reflect the record types this way
PS: Google documentation here asks not to map the CNAME record.
Any idea - what can I do to get this right?
